# A particular content type forces preview before save. How do I turn this off?

Tags: 7, nodes

I've set up a new content type, but for this (and none of my other custom content types), it forces a preview before the save button appears.

Is there a way I can turn this off? I've looked around and can't see an obvious option to turn it off, but maybe I'm being blind. It's really frustrating.

Comment: For the Drupal 6 answer, see this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98977/why-does-my-content-type-need-to-be-reviewed-before-it-can-be-saved?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set this option easily:

1. Edit the content type
2. Click *"Submission form settings"*
3. Set *"Preview before submitting"* to *Optional* (or *Disabled* if you don't want previews at all).

Comment: You're welcome :) Just tick this as the accepted answer if it answers your question well.

Comment: Hah, you know I tried, but it wouldn't let me because it was too soon after posting my question... All done now though.