# Why does my content type need to be reviewed before it can be saved?

Tags: nodes, entities

I created a new content type and when I want to create new content of this content type, on the bottom I only get the `Preview` button, the `Save` button does not show up and I can not find in the content type settigns how I disable this "must preview before save"-feature...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7, you can manage this via `admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE` in the Submission form settings:

[image]

In Drupal 6, you manage this via `admin/content/node-settings`:

[image]